# Solspace User 3.4.6 Registration error on dev server - EE 2.7.3

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, registration

I am using Solspace User for new member registration. I've installed the demo templates and attempting to register a new user. Submission of the registration form throws the following errors:

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$csrf_hidden_name  Filename: user/mod.user.php  Line Number: 5955

This is followed by a series of "headers already sent" errors.

Oddly, the new user is successfully saved to the members table, and can subsequently login successfully.

Using EE 2.7.3 and Solspace User 3.4.6

Update: I then regressed back to User 3.4.5, and it works successfully w/ EE 2.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a possible bug. Try this:

In mod.user.php, on line 5955 (User 3.4.6), change

```
$good = ee()->input->get_post($this->sc->csrf_hidden_name);
```

to

```
$good = ee()->input->get_post($this->sc->csrf_name);
```

Comment: Works, however, this full fix requires a similar edit in line 5982.